# What's the best way to make a mobile friendly site?

Tags: mobile

Speaking entirely in technology-free terms, what is the best way to make a mobile friendly site?  That is, I want to make a site that will work on a regular computer but also have mobile versions of the pages.  Should I rewrite each page?  The pages will probably have different functionality, so should I rewrite the backend code?  Should it be an effectively different site with the same database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a mobile presentation layer to an operational site about a year ago. Based on the architecture of the site (hopefully this isn't too technology dependent for you) I added a new set of JSPs to accommodate mobile browsers (sidenote: see http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ for a great way to build mobile pages independent of browser type). Additionally some of the back-end functionality was changed due to the limited functionality of most mobile browsers. So, in short, the integration wasn't as painful as one would expect.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, I am using rails, but it looks like I can use wurfl with rails.  Thanks!

Comment: Marking it down to combat WUFRL device dependent engineering.

Answer (score 2):

On my [site](http://www.bowlsk.com), I detect user agent, and for known mobile browsers I serve a different stylesheet, with some larger/less necessary items left off some pages.  The backend doesn't really change.

Comment: I would agree with this, or even take it a step further...

Detect for known mobile browsers and redirect to a different domain (i.e. http://mobile.yoursite.com).  You can use the same data access/business rules if you have each of these separated by projects within your solution.

Comment: True.  I am using GAE as a host, which ties an application to a single domain, so I would not be able to get at the same datastore with 2 version of an app.  Good idea for systems that would support it though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question, but here goes:

- If the site is primarily about the content, meaning it's not so much a service you use as it's a publication you read, then I'd try to avoid publishing two sites wherever possible. Concentrate on simple presentation using mature technologies that mobile browsers can handle fairly well.
- If it's essentially a software application delivered via the network, then things get trickier, because you're going to want to consider the UI of the mobile device, and how it differs from the desktop.
- This should go without saying, but either way, if you have many mobile users, you should keep that in mind when you author content for the site. Formats, length, voice, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the WURFL / WALL capabilities system that todd mentioned, there are Java Server Faces libraries available that use alternate WML renderkits for mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have done it in the past was to make sure my data was abstracted well in the data tier and then use separate middle tier models to pull what was appropriate. In my case the application was a weather application and the display methods of the target devices were really limited so we opted to only show the user the essentials on the mobile devices while the website was full featured. That was probably 10 years ago when WAP was big. But these days with devices getting bigger screens, better bandwidth, you may want to consume and display the exact same data with a different view model.

I never really know what type of application will need to consume the data in the future. We do a lot of apps across platforms but the domain model rarely changes. So I end up using the same middle tier objects where I can and pulling that data in different clients. A good example of this is a recent project where we had a rich internet application (widget), a full website, and a web service consuming the same data. Data abstraction in the middle-tier really shines in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

On a very high level of abstraction, there are two main caveats with mobile devices: (1) their screen is small, (2) their network connection is intermittent. This basically means that your need to present the content so that it looks fine even on a small (variable size) screen, and preferably make it cacheable too so that your users can browse the content while offline. Then there's also the problem of low bandwidth and high latency, but those are slightly less important nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very thorough overview of how to make a site mobile, though i hope its fair to say that there will always be different requirements for anyone seeking to go mobile. If you have a Blog, then you could just as easily make it mobile friendly using Mippin Mobilizer; its free, provides branding customisation tools, and with a big audience already browsing a wide mix of mobilized content, there's opportunities to generate advertising revenue around your blog.

This is because the Mippin Mobilized blog then becomes part of a much wider community of content, people, news, blogs, listings, all connecting around content, and much more at the mobile site:

http://mippin.com (on a mobile browser.)

Take a look at the Mobilizing tool because it shows off what the site can do in a second:

www.mippin.com/mobilizer

Only if you have a blog of course...